# project.json doesn't have a runtimes section, add '"runtimes": { "win": { } }' to project.json

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-build-task

Build definition in VSTS used to work fine till yesterday afternoon but suddenly it started failing while building functional tests solution(written in specflow and .Net core ).

Error: `Your project.json doesn't have a runtimes section. You should add '"runtimes": { "win": { } }' to your project.json and then re-run NuGet restore`
Locally also I was facing the same issue but it got resolved once I deleted the obj folder, restored packages and rebuilded solution but same issue is there on VSTS and I am not sure how to fix it.

I have tried work around
 `https://github.com/Belorus/EventStream/commit/d04f247feb13347ec565bd6d1e0fe71c5171ca55#diff-c384bfaa54e70831c87232eefe73e359` 
but it didn't help me either.

I am using nuget version 1* and target frame work is net461 most importantly project extension is .csproj which doesn't have project.json file.

Comment: Do you use private agent? What's the version of your Visual Studio? What're steps to reproduce this issue? What're tasks of your build definition?

Comment: thanks for the response, It was in a private agent running on vs2017. Usual build solution task but i got the issue it was failing because of project build template. We have migrated solution from VS2015 to VS2017 sometime back but then it was not giving any issue so far, since yesterday afternoon it started failing and once I changed the project build template to use newer format it started going green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in a private agent running on vs2017. Usual build solution task was failing but i got the issue, it was failing because of project build template. We have migrated solution from VS2015 to VS2017 sometime back but then it was not giving any issue so far, since yesterday afternoon it started failing and once I changed the project build template to use newer format it started going green.